# How can I deal damage with melee in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making game and I am using sword as a weapon so I have created a script and detect hit by collider of sword to deal damage but I am getting problem that it is dealing damage whenever sword collide with enemy collider even if player is not in state of attacking suggest me a script for melee attack damage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more code / resources for us to properly evaluate the issue. Although, I think I get what your problem is. You should disable the collider when the character is not attack. This will stop any accidental triggers happening when not in combat.